# Casting string to generic type that is a string

Tags: c#, string, generics, casting

I'm writing a method to do a intelligent type conversion - using ToString() if the type parameter happens to be a string, otherwise casting but returning null if the cast doesn't work. Basically gets as much information out of `v` it can without throwing an exception.

I check that `T` is indeed a `string` before I attempt the cast, but the compiler is still not a fan:

```
Cannot convert type 'string' to 'T'
```

And here's my method:

```
public T? Convert<T>(object v)
{
    if (typeof(T) == typeof(string)) {
    return (T)v.ToString(); // Cannot convert type 'string' to 'T'  
    } else try {
      return (T)v;
    } catch (InvalidCastException) {
    return null;
    }
}
```

Also let me know if this is some sort of unforgivable sin. I'm using it to deal with some data structures that could have mixed types.

Comment: There are other problems. Your method cannot have return type `T?` when there's no constraint on `T`. For example there's nothing called `string?` because string is a reference type.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You basically need to go via `object` when casting to a generic type:

```
return (T)(object) v.ToString()
```

and

```
return (T)(object) v;
```

I would use `is` rather than catching an `InvalidCastException` though.

See [Eric Lippert's recent blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2012/07/10/when-is-a-cast-not-a-cast.aspx) for more details of why this is necessary.

In particular:

> Because the compiler knows that the only way this conversion could possibly succeed is if `U` is bool, but `U` can be anything! The compiler assumes that most of the time `U` is not going to be constructed with `bool`, and therefore this code is almost certainly an error, and the compiler is bringing that fact to your attention.

(Substitute `T` for `U` and `string` for `bool`...)

Comment: Wouldn't `as` be the better choice here?

Comment: @SteveCzetty: We don't know that `T` is a nullable type, so `as` wouldn't work (IIRC).

Comment: Good point.  Though I don't think `is` will work either, unless `T` is constrained to a `class`.  (IIRC, also)

Comment: @SteveCzetty: Yes it will - you can use `is` with any kind of type. For example: `object o = 10; if (o is int) ...`

Comment: @BehnamEsmaili: where is the value type that would be boxed?

Answer (score 3):

You need to cast your string as `object` as your return type is generic i.e.

```
return (T)(object)v.ToString();
```

Comment: That's not boxing. There are no value types involved.

Answer (score 0):

Try to convert to `object` before converting to `T`

```
return (T)(object)v;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.ComponentModel;
```

...

```
public T Convert<T>(object v) {
    return (T)TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(T)).ConvertFrom(v);
}
```

Warning, this will throw an exception if no conversion exists between T and the object contained in v.