# Unexpected behavior of "as" operator, it differs from plain cast

Tags: c#, .net, casting

I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21432141/why-i-cannot-cast-derived-generic-type-to-base-non-generic-type-through-a-const). This code doesn't compile (*"Cannot convert `Generic<T>` to `T`"*) because of the reason explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21432252/1207195) (even if I'd expect an `InvalidCastException` at run-time **instead of** a compile-time error).

```
class NonGeneric
{
}

class Generic<T> : NonGeneric
    where T : NonGeneric
{
    T DoSomething()
    {
        return (T)this; // ** Cannot convert...
    }
}
```

Accepted solution gave this workaround:

```
T DoSomething()
{
    return this as T;
}
```

My question is: **why**? `as` operator should be exactly equivalent to cast operator:

> The as operator is like a cast operation. However, if the conversion isn't possible, as returns null instead of raising an exception.

If `this as T` should be equivalent to `this is T? (T)this: (T)null` then why `as T` works and `(T)this` doesn't even compile? AFAIK cast could be used in a more wide range of situations than `as`:

> Note that the as operator performs only reference conversions, nullable conversions, and boxing conversions. The as operator can't perform other conversions, such as user-defined conversions, which should instead be performed by using cast expressions.

Then why this? Is it a documented feature of `as` operator? Is it a compiler/language limitation with generic types? Note that this code compiles fine:

```
return (T)((object)this);
```

Is this because compiler can't be sure if `T` is `dynamic` (even if there is a `where` constraint) then it'll always generate such code?

Comment: The compilation error says that you are inheriting `NonGeneric<T>`. Is that the compiler being confused, or is the code sample inaccurate?

Comment: Does the `DoSomething()` function return a `T` object or `null`?

Comment: @KeithPayne sorry, wrong error message. fixed

Comment: @Adriano can you clarify your question **Why?** Why what?

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy why cast doesn't compile but as does (moreover see last code example for same thing done with cast).

Comment: @TimSchmelter yes, I found it (see my last edit) but this made me surprised. I wonder if this is a compiler problem or something else I don't know!

Comment: @Adriano: related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11866282/284240

Comment: The cast fails because the compiler cannot verify at compile-time that the cast is safe to do. `as` and the double cast through `object` simply tells the compiler to trust you, even though you can't be sure either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It says in the C# Language Specification (emphasis mine),

> If the compile-time type of E is not dynamic, the operation E as T produces the same result as
>   E is T ? (T)(E) : (T)null
>   except that E is only evaluated once. The compiler can be expected to optimize E as T to perform at most one dynamic type check as opposed to the two dynamic type checks implied by the expansion above.
>
> **If the compile-time type of E is `dynamic`**, unlike the cast operator the `as` operator is not dynamically bound (§7.2.2). Therefore the expansion in this case is:
>   `E is T ? (T)(object)(E) : (T)null`

This seems to be the reason why the compilation succeed using `as` or when `this` is cast to an object first. Furthermore,

> In an operation of the form `E as T`, `E` must be an expression and `T` must be a reference type, a type parameter known to be a reference type, or a nullable type. Furthermore, at least one of the following must be true, or otherwise a compile-time error occurs:
>
> •  An identity (§6.1.1), implicit nullable (§6.1.4), implicit reference (§6.1.6), boxing (§6.1.7), explicit nullable (§6.2.3), explicit reference (§6.2.4), or unboxing (§6.2.5) conversion exists from `E` to `T`.
>
> •  **The type of `E` or `T` is an open type.**
>
> •  `E` is the `null` literal.

Which is the current case with your generic class.

Comment: In my case it's not dynamic but I suppose compiler doesn't complain because of that! Thank you!

Comment: Jackpot! I'm pretty sure the MSDN docs failed to include this little detail.

Comment: Why is there emphasis on `dynamic`? I don't see how the DLR is involved here.

Comment: Because under those circumstances (the expression is `dynamic` or, I'm assuming, `generic` in nature), the `as` operator will first cast the expression to `object` before casting to `T`. It explains why using `as expression` or `(T)((object)expression)` was permissible, whereas `(T)expression` was not.

Comment: @RitchMelton yes, even if it shouldn't, because here we have just generics and no dynamic, if there isn't something else...I suppose it's a compiler _problem_...

Comment: ...well maybe @EricLippert may take some light on this if he'll ever read this post.

Comment: @Adriano Yes, it is strange behavior altogether, and Eric Lippert does mention (in [the post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2012/07/10/when-is-a-cast-not-a-cast.aspx) from the related question) that by casting to `object` you circumvent the compiler's notion of `T`'s type; and the real question would be why `as` decides to cast to `object` first, my guess being, because the expression `E` is of a generic type.

Comment: @rae1 IMO you're completely right. This conversion doesn't fall in the _most of cases_ bag so compiler complains. Anyway strange "as" behavior!

Answer (score 5):

According to [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscsdfbt.aspx):-

> The as operator is like a cast operation. However, if the conversion isn't possible, as returns null instead of raising an exception
>
> The code is equivalent to the following expression except that the expression variable is evaluated only one time.

```
    expression is type ? (type)expression : (type)null
```

Another difference is that:-

> Note that the as operator performs only reference conversions, nullable conversions, and boxing conversions. The as operator can't perform other conversions, such as user-defined conversions, which should instead be performed by using cast expressions.

Comment: -1 No, that's what I'd expect but it's **not** equivalent because (type)expression fails even to compile. That's why my question...

Comment: It fails to compile because,  the compiler knows that the cast will fail(at compile time) but in case of `as` it has the option of returning null(if the cast fails) so it compiles succesfully.

Comment: **No**, cast **may** fail at run-time. It shouldn't reject it (see edit for another case). At least it should reject both cast and "as" operator...

Answer (score -5):

'as' operator in C# performs these actions:-

1. It returns null if given variable is not of given type of any of its base types. It   doesnt   throw any exception
2. Can be only applied with reference type variables.
3. 'as' does not do any conversion (implicit/explicit)

'as' operator is slightly faster than any casting (even in cases where there are no invalid casts which would severely lower casting's performance due to exceptions).